# How to find unused code over a group of projects?

Tags: .net-core, static-analysis, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

In my solution, I would like to detect unused code in an automated way as part of the CI. More specifically, I want to analyze a group of projects (e.g. those under `/src` but not `/test`) and then decide within that scope what is used and what not. For example: a `public` method in a lower-level project *should* be identified as unused if none of the referencing projects within the same group are using it (some tools do not detect that because a `public` member can potentially also be used outside of the solution but I'm not interested in that as I'm writing a product and not a library to be consumed).

Some years ago, I was able to achieve this using FxCop by setting up an FxCop project that would contain the relevant projects and then did the analysis against those.

Today, in the .NET Core world, it seems that the Roslyn Analyzers are the way to go (I might be wrong here and please let me know if there are better alternatives for the job) but I don't know how I can setup a ruleset that spans multiple projects and if analyzers would be able to detect unused code as described. Looking at articles such as [Write Better Code Faster with Roslyn Analyzers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/write-better-code-faster-with-roslyn-analyzers/), it seems that rulesets are only targeting one project (namely for which the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers) is installed).

Comment: If you could integrate your code with SonarQube it is possible to give the unused code through code analysis metrics

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default NDepend rule-set for that, that has rules to detect [Unused Types](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1700#!), [Unused Methods](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1701#!) and [Unused Fields](https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1702#!).

The tool can analyze any .NET Core or .NET Framework code.

The scope of an NDepend project can spawn several or all VS projects of a VS solution, and even several VS solutions.

*>I want to analyze a group of projects (e.g. those under /src but not /test) and then decide within that scope what is used and what not.*

[NDepend code rules are editable C# LINQ queries](https://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL) so you can easily edit or duplicate a default rule to enforce some restriction like:

```
from t in JustMyCode.Types
   .Where(t1 => t1.ParentNamespace.FullNameLike("*YourRegexPattern*")) 
where t.NbTypesUsingMe == 0 && canTypeBeConsideredAsDeadProc(t)
select t
...
```

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*